# Azure Fabric Service Deployment Locations

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'd like transition our Cloud Services to the Azure Fabric Service.  However, all of our other infrastructure is located in the Central US region.  In the Azure Portal, there is no option to create an Azure Service Fabric cluster in the Central US region.

Could I use an ARM Template to create a Fabric Service Cluster in the Central US region?  Or is the lack of an option in the portal an indication that the Fabric Service Cluster is just not an option in Central US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/?cdn=disable for service status, and options.  You will see that SF is not in Central US

Comment: Thanks for the link.  But that doesn't answer the question of whether or not it can be done manually with an ARM template.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It cannot be done manually as the service simply isn't available in that region as per the link

Answer (score 0):

Service Fabric is avaible in CENTRAL US at least now. In ARM template you can specify the location of cluster using parameter.